# Is there a way to find out if hosted code on sourceforge is svn or cvs and script the download process?

Tags: svn, cvs, sourceforge

For instance, is there a way for me to use svn or cvs (and how to find out which?) for a project if I have their project page -- for example, http://sourceforge.net/projects/ecb/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking on the [Source](http://sourceforge.net/scm/?type=cvs&group_id=17484) page for that project, it gives the CVS command

`cvs -d:pserver:anonymous@ecb.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/ecb login`

Other projects that use CVS should follow the same naming convention. SVN looks to be similar:

`svn co https://<project>.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/<project>`

Answer (score 1):

Something tells me you want to 'screen-scrape' to figure out which revision control a project uses. The project page has the link to the main 'Code' page which you can `grep` out by looking for the word `scm`. For e.g:
The command (in unix, say):

```
curl -s http://sourceforge.net/projects/<project-short-name>/ | \
grep 'scm/?type' | sed 's/\(.*type=\)\([a-z]\+\)\(&amp.*\)$/\2/g'
```

Should get you the words `svn` or `cvs` or both (or even other words ?) from the html links. This is just to illustrate how you can figure out the SCM a project uses programatically. You might have 
to write more or less code depending on where you want to 'script' this i.e. Questions like, is it on unix or windows ? is it for an eclipse plugin ? and many more come to mind.

**Disclaimer**: Many websites consider screen scraping a violation of the Terms of Service. Please check the sf.net policy to see if its ok to scrape the web-page before you do.

Comment: This is indeed be nice but I will stick with manually looking up for now...